# JSONB Array Update for Specific Element

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb array with around 1000 elements of the structure "oid: aaa, instance:bbb, value:ccc".

```
{"_id": 37637070
, "data": [{"oid": "11.5.15.1.4", "value": "1", "instance": "1.1.4"}
         , {"oid": "11.5.15.1.9", "value": "17", "instance": "1.1.4"}
         , {"oid": "12.5.15.1.5", "value": "0.0.0.0", "instance": "0"}]}
```

I have an index on this field

```
CREATE INDEX configuration_my_idx ON configuration
USING gin ((config->'data') jsonb_path_ops);
```

search is very fast, however I did not find a fast way to do update. I would like to update a value for a specific oid and instance combination.

For example, update value to "18" when oid is "11.5.15.1.9" and instance is "1.1.4"

What is the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: What's your current (slow) way of doing an update here? So we can use that as a reference whether other approaches are really faster or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PostgreSQL 11+

If you're already at PostgreSQL v. 11 (because of the [new `JSONB` type conversion support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.7.5.8)) your best bet would probably be a custom function written in Perl or Python.

As I favor Python 3, here is a functional example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_replace_in_array (val jsonb, path_to_array text[], replacement jsonb, entry_filters jsonb)
    RETURNS jsonb
    TRANSFORM FOR TYPE jsonb
    LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $$
v_new = val
tmp = v_new
for e in path_to_array:
    tmp = tmp[e]

for item in tmp:
    if (entry_filters is None or entry_filters.items() <= item.items()):
        item.update(replacement)

return v_new
$$;
```

...which then can be used as follows:

```sql
UPDATE configuration
SET
  config = jsonb_replace_in_array(
    config,
    '{data}',
    '{"value":"changed"}'::jsonb,
    '{"oid":"11.5.15.1.4","instance":"1.1.4"}'::jsonb
  )
WHERE config->'data' @> '[{"oid":"11.5.15.1.4","instance":"1.1.4"}]';
```

So yes, the condition is duplicated, but only to limit the amount of rows to touch in the first place.

To actually work at a plain PostgreSQL 11 installation, you need extensions `plpython3u` and `jsonb_plpython3u`:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
CREATE EXTENSION jsonb_plpython3u;
```

The Python logic explained:

```py
for e in path_to_array:
    tmp = tmp[e]
```

...gets us down to the array of entries we need to look at.

```py
for item in tmp:
    if (entry_filters is None or entry_filters.items() <= item.items()):
        item.update(replacement)
```

...for each item in the array, we check whether the filter criteria is `null` (`entry_filters is None` = match any entry) or whether the entry "contains" the provided example including keys and values (`entry_filters.items() <= item.items()`).

If en entry matches, then overwrite/add contents with the provided replacement.

I hope that goes into the direction you where looking for.

Looking at the current capabilities of PostgreSQL related to JSON modification it would be very complex (if not complicated) and introduce a lot of overhead to do the same with pure SQL.

---

### PostgreSQL 9.6+

In case you don't have version 11 available yet, the following function will do the same at the expense of handling the type conversions by itself but keep it completely API-compatible, so you once you upgrade, the only thing you have to do is replace the function (no change to any statements using this function required):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_replace_in_array (val jsonb, path_to_array text[], replacement jsonb, entry_filters jsonb)
    RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $$
import json

v_new = json.loads(val)
t_replace = json.loads(replacement)
t_filters = json.loads(entry_filters)
tmp = v_new
for e in path_to_array:
    tmp = tmp[e]

for item in tmp:
    if (entry_filters is None or t_filters.items() <= item.items()):
        item.update(t_replace)

return json.dumps(v_new)
$$;
```

Comment: Thank you Ancoron for the very detailed answer.  Unfortunately I'm using Postgres 9.6 and cannot upgrade at the moment.

Comment: No problem, I'll figure out a version for 9.6 then... :)