# Postgres jsonb document storage like mongo

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have simple table like this

```
CREATE TABLE things (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data jsonb
);
```

and i want to store complex nested json like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
        "title": "thing",
        "things": [
            {
                "title": "thing 1",
                "moreThings": [
                    { "title": "more thing 1" }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

but i found it difficult to insert and manipulate complex nested json.
i want to do same thing as mongo's push and populate, can i achieve same functionality with postgres json storage? if i can how? or is it an anti pattern and i should just write normal tables with relations?

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: Why don't you normalize your model, then manipulating individual items gets really easy. Postgres is a relational database, it is not a "document store" - if you need that, use a document database.  If you find yourself in need to manipulate JSON documents on a very fine level, you are mis-using the JSON type. Think about normalizing your data model.

Comment: I gave you my opinion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060319/6464308).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because i want to query one whole document with all of its data as single json

Comment: Apparently it's not a "whole document", otherwise you wouldn't need to access/update individual keys inside that document.

Comment: If you want a JSON document store **like** MongoDB, then why not **just use** MongoDB?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes but it gets more complicated when i want to insert inside nested arrays nested array with specific field

Comment: my final question is just can i do same as mongodb's push and populate with postgres?

Comment: TL;DR: No, not out-of-the-box at the moment. But you can always write simple functions that do what you want without a lot of standard function chaining, aso. e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048442/jsonb-array-update-for-specific-element